# How to add sitemap.xml to the root directory of website in Azure?

Tags: asp.net, azure, deployment

For SEO purposes, I created `sitemap.xml` for our ASP.NET Core 6 MVC.  This file needs to be located directly in the website root folder. The website is hosted in Azure.  When deploy website code from developer's workstation to Azure using Visual Studio 2022, the `sitemap.xml` is not included in deployment package.

It looks like static files that are not under `wwwroot` folder will not be deployed using VS 2022 deployment function.

Is there any special deployment settings I can use to include static files located in the root folder? If I put static file under `wwwroot`, after the deployment, will I be able to move it from `wwwroot` directory to root dir?

Comment: Where you have created the `site map.xml` in your local folder ? In the root directory?

Comment: And also right click the xml file and check the file properties. The Copy to Output  has to be set to Copy once or Copy always.

Comment: When deploy from developer's machine to Azure using Publish function in VS, the sitemap.xml file in the output folder still won't be deploymed to Azure.  The static files that are not regular ASP.NET file have to be placed under wwwroot folder in order to be deployed to Azure.  In Azure portal, the file can be moved to root folder from wwwtool using the Advanced tools.

Comment: My website is ASP.NET CORE 6 MVC.  According to my test, when sitemap.xml is located under wwwroot, the URL of https://www.myTestSite.com/sitemap.xml will display xml file content.  But, if the file is only under the website root, using same URL will ended up with HTTP 404 error: page not found.  I think this behavior is determined by the routing rule in MVC.  When adding sitemap to Google Search Console, you have to use the URL for accessing sitemap.xml.  So, it seems to me that the sitemap.xml file actually needs to be in wwwroot folder for SEO purposes. I'm not sure whether it is correct.

Comment: Checking from my end.Will let you know if it is working for me.

Comment: Iam able to access the [file](https://i.imgur.com/Krjkx8H.png) which is in the application root directory.Will post an answer in detail.

Comment: Are you still facing the issue ? Check the below solution to access the static files from root folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a sample `sitemap.xml` under the application root folder.

[image]

- Initially even I got the 404 error when I tried to access the file.
- Whenever you add any file, Initially the properties of the file will be

```cs
 Build Action - None
 Copy to Output Directory - Do not Copy
```

- Change the properties as below

```cs
 Build Action - Content
 Copy to Output Directory - Copy if newer
```

[image]

- I have referred this [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-8.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root) to serve the static files outside the `wwwroot` folder.
- Added the below code in   `Program.cs` file.

```cs
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
           Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "")),
    RequestPath = ""
});
```

- As my xml file is under the root directory, so the `ContentRootPath` and `RequestPath` is null.
- Deployed the app to Azure App Service using Publish option.
- Now I am able to see the `xml` file under `wwwroot` folder.

[image]

***Output:***

[image]